# Find closest values to a list of integers

Tags: r, function

How can I create a vector `S`, with

`S[i] = 1, if Tv[i]` is the closest number to an integer in `I<- 6:10`
`S[i] = 0 else`

```
Tv <- c(5.946, 5.978, 
6.01, 6.043, 6.075, 6.109, 6.14, 6.173, 6.205, 6.239, 
6.273, 6.309, 6.344, 6.379, 6.415, 6.45, 6.486, 6.521, 6.556, 
6.59, 6.627, 6.665, 6.703, 6.741, 6.778, 6.816, 6.852, 6.891, 
6.928, 6.967, 7.005, 7.045, 7.084, 7.124, 7.161, 7.202, 7.24)

S <- getS(Tv)

> dput(S) 
c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ....)
```

Final goal is to have a list like a ruler with `1` where the value is closest to the next integer value.

Comment: Don't call a variable `T`, because that is a short-cut for `TRUE` in R.

Comment: Indeed. And on that note, don't use `T` as shortcut for `TRUE` or `F` as shortcut for `FALSE` because people tend to assign variables with those names anyway.

Comment: Good point. In fact my variable is mydf$T that should be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
I <- 6:10
S <- numeric(length(T))
S[sapply(I, function(i) which.min(abs(i - T)))] <- 1
S
[1] 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

Comment: why do you have 1 at the end?

Comment: Because the last number is closest to 8, 9, 10 which are in `I`

Comment: but It don't give the same result as other solution!

Comment: Your solution probably is for a different problem than this, i.e. you are looking for the closest number to the _further_ integer. While mine and @Roland solutions do compare e.g. `5.99` and `6.02`. Yes, that is unclear whether it is necessary to consider 8, 9, 10. Possibly it is, since this solution was accepted.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't require you to give `I`, but just looks up values closest to the nearest integer:

```
test <- c(5.946, 5.978,6.01, 6.043, 6.075, 6.109, 6.14, 6.173, 6.205, 6.239, 6.273, 6.309, 6.344, 6.379, 6.415,
       6.45, 6.486, 6.521, 6.556, 6.59, 6.627, 6.665, 6.703, 6.741, 6.778, 6.816, 6.852, 6.891,
       6.928, 6.967, 7.005, 7.045, 7.084, 7.124, 7.161, 7.202, 7.24)

res <- integer(length(test))
res[abs(test-round(test)) %in% c(by(test,round(test),
                                    FUN=function(test) min(abs(test-round(test)))))] <- 1
#[1] 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

One line solution

```
diff(floor(c(T[1],T)))
```

Comment: This depends on the vector being ordered.

Comment: @Roland you are right but I gave the solution to the example given in the question.

Comment: The result is correct by chance, but not because it solves the question.